# Create new Image Rendition in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, image-rendition

Is it possible to create a new Image Rendition using PowerShell?

I have only been able to find .Net or XML solutions, such as...

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spsite")) {
    ImageRenditionCollection imageRenditions = SiteImageRenditions.GetRenditions(site);

    ImageRendition rendition = new ImageRendition {
        Name = "New Rendition",
        Width = 295,
        Height = 295
    };

    imageRenditions.Add(rendition);
    imageRenditions.Update();
}
```

Can this be replicated in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .NET assemblies in PowerShell, which makes it so powerful.

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$site = Get-SPSite "http://spsite"
$imageRenditions =  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.SiteImageRenditions]::GetRenditions($site)

        $rendition = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.ImageRendition
        $rendition.Name = "New Rendition"
        $rendition.Width = 295
        $rendition.Height = 295

$imageRenditions.Add($rendition)
$imageRenditions.Update()
$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: Do you know where the documentation is for this? I searched for a long time and couldn't find this. I'm out of the office this week so I'll have to give this a try when I'm back in next week. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a factor of documentation for this in powershell, just the know-how on how to translate .NET code into powershell.